# How can I create a 'rewrite' for a path in Termux

Tags: linux, bash, make, android

#### Problem

I'm on Termux, and on Termux it's not `/usr`, it's `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr`.

This causes problems at times when running scripts (mostly bash and make) that weren't designed with Termux in mind.

#### My intention

Everytime a script wants to open a file at path starting from `/usr`, I want it to be 'rewritten' to the valid path.

Any solution other solution that tackles the problem is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "use `sed` to change all occurrences of `/usr` to `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr` in your scripts". e.g.

```
sed -i -e 's=/usr=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr=g' *.sh
```

The trouble with this is: if some or all of the `/usr` paths have already been changed to `/data/data/.../usr`, then they will be changed again, ending up as `/data/data/com.termux/files/data/data/com.termux/files/usr`.  e.g.

```
$ echo /usr | sed -e 's=/usr=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr=g'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr

$ echo /data/data/com.termux/files/usr | sed -e 's=/usr=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr=g'
/data/data/com.termux/files/data/data/com.termux/files/usr
```

To solve, only allow /usr to be changed if it's preceded by a space or the start of the line:

```
$ echo /data/data/com.termux/files/usr | sed -e 's=\(^\|[[:space:]]\)/usr=\1/data/data/com.termux/files/usr=g'
```

Or slightly more readable with extended regular expressions:

```
$ echo /data/data/com.termux/files/usr | sed -E -e 's=(^|[[:space:]])/usr=\1/data/data/com.termux/files/usr='
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr
```

---

*The following was written before I remembered that look-behind isn't necessary (IMO, it's a "better" more-generally-useful solution, but not required)....left in mostly because it's useful info and I don't want to delete it:*

Alternatively, you could use a regex feature called "negative look-behind".  Unfortunately, sed does not support look-behinds or look-aheads(*).

Perl does support look-arounds, so you could use that instead if you have perl installed with Termux (it has been a long time since I last used termux, so I can't remember if base perl is included with it or not.  It's certainly an installable package).  e.g.

```
perl -i -p -e 's=(?<!/data/data/com.termux/files/)/usr=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr=g' *.sh
```

(BTW, with its `-p` option, perl works similarly to sed as a tool to modify stdin or files.  With its `-n` option, perl works similarly to `sed -n`.  This is intentional - this usage of perl is meant to be a drop-in replacement sed-like tool enhanced with the full power of perl).

Alternatively, the negative look-behind can avoid changing /usr if **ANY** alpha-numeric or `/` character(s) come immediately before `/usr`:

```
perl -i -p -e 's=(?<![[:alnum:]/])/usr=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr=g' *.sh
```

You can see below that /usr is only changed if it's by itself:

```
$ echo /usr | perl -pe 's=(?<![[:alnum:]/])/usr=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr=g'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr

$ echo /data/data/com.termux/files/usr | perl -pe 's=(?<![[:alnum:]/])/usr=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr=g'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr

$ echo /foo/bar/usr | perl -pe 's=(?<![[:alnum:]/])/usr=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr=g'
/foo/bar/usr
```

(*) The only version of sed I know of that does support look-arounds is Super Sed or [ssed](http://sed.sf.net/grabbag/ssed/) (the home page is not working at the moment). `ssed` seems to be abandon-ware and hasn't been updated for many years - it was based on GNU sed 3.02 from 1998 while current GNU sed is version 4.8 from 2020.  `ssed` is packaged for Debian so is probably available for Termux too.  But if you're going to install it, you may as well just use perl.

Anyway, `ssed` has a `-R` option which allows it to use Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, [PCRE](https://pcre.org/).

```
$ echo /data/data/com.termux/files/usr | ssed -R 's=(?<![[:alnum:]/])/usr=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr='
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr

$ echo /foo/bar/usr | ssed -R 's=(?<![[:alnum:]/])/usr=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr='
/foo/bar/usr
```